# Очередность действий js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

помогите решить проблему.
Есть задача, имеются какие-то строки выведенные в html через php. Нужно сделать кнопку удаления, с подтверждением удаления через ajax. И вот что у меня получилось:

Код js:

```
$('.form-btn-delete-confirm').click(function (e) {
    $(this).clearQueue();
    // TODO: починить
    e.preventDefault();
    let uri = null;
    let id = null;
    uri = $(this).attr('action');
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let response;
    console.log('click-delete');
    $('#btn-delete-confirm').click(function () {
        console.log('click-confirm');
        $.ajax({
            url: `${uri}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
            },
            success: (data) => {
                console.log('success');
                $('#modal-delete-confirm').modal('hide');
                response = data;
                $(`tr[data-id="${id}"]`).remove();
                notyf.success({
                    message: response.message
                });
            },
            error: (data) => {
                console.log('error');
                $('#modal-delete-confirm').modal('hide');
                response = data.responseJSON;
                notyf.error({
                    message: response.message
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

В коде я поставил чекпоинты с выводом в консоль, чтобы смотреть, где сейчас код отрабатывает.

И вот такой код laravel.blade.php

```
<td class="border-0 align-middle">
    <a href="{{ route('nomenclatures.edit', $nomenclature['id']) }}">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" type="button">Редактировать</button>
    </a>
    <form action="{{ route('nomenclatures.destroy', $nomenclature['id']) }}" data-id="{{ $nomenclature['id'] }}" class="form-btn-delete-confirm" method="POST"
                                  style="display: inline-block">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-delete-confirm">Удалить</button>
    </form>
</td>


<div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete-confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-delete-confirm" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="h6 modal-title">Удаление</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Подтвердите удаление</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-delete-confirm">Удалить</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-gray ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

У меня это работает, если нажать кнопку отмены, то удаление отменяется. Но если отменить допустим 3 раза, а на 4 раз подтвердить, то 1 раз удалится, и 3 раза выдаст ошибку о том, что такого элемента не существует. Почему так?
Я полагаю, что отмененные действия как-то сохраняются и применяются когда произошло событие клика на кнопку подтверждения и я не знаю как это исправить.

Вот скрин консоли, ниже опишу мои действия

[image: Консоль]

Я 2 раза нажимаю на `.form-btn-delete-confirm` и оба раза в модальном окне отменяю удаление.
Далее, я нажимаю еще раз на `.form-btn-delete-confirm` и подтверждаю удаление нажатием нажатием на `#btn-delete-confirm` и в консоли видно, как будто я 3 раза нажал на `#btn-delete-confirm`. И соответственно произошло 3 ajax запроса. 1 успех и 2 неудачи, так как этого элементе в БД уже нет.
Что мне с этим делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо дело в том что при каждом нажатии на .form-btn-delete-confirm, в обработчике Вы создаёте каждый раз ещё один обработчик уже для #btn-delete-confirm, таким образом несколько нажатий на .form-btn-delete-confirm зарегистрирует несколько обработчиков #btn-delete-confirm, при нажатии на который у Вас отработают зарегистрированные ранее обработчики. Соответственно 3 нажатия на .form-btn-delete-confirm порождает 3 обработчика #btn-delete-confirm, и теперь при нажатии на #btn-delete-confirm, сработают эти три обработчика и каждый выполнить этот код. Соответственно первый раз ajax удалит, а оставшиеся уже не найдут эту запись и вернут 404.

Исходя из выше сказанного необходимо вынести регистрацию обработчика #btn-delete-confirm, из обработчика .form-btn-delete-confirm
Например вот так:

```
$('.form-btn-delete-confirm').click(function (e) {
    $(this).clearQueue();
    // TODO: починить
    e.preventDefault();
    let uri = null;
    let id = null;
    uri = $(this).attr('action');
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let response;
    console.log('click-delete');
});

$('#btn-delete-confirm').click(function () {
        console.log('click-confirm');
        $.ajax({
            url: `${uri}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
            },
            success: (data) => {
                console.log('success');
                $('#modal-delete-confirm').modal('hide');
                response = data;
                $(`tr[data-id="${id}"]`).remove();
                notyf.success({
                    message: response.message
                });
            },
            error: (data) => {
                console.log('error');
                $('#modal-delete-confirm').modal('hide');
                response = data.responseJSON;
                notyf.error({
                    message: response.message
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Да, спасибо вам огромное, ваше решение работает, что было довольно логично. Только переменные `uri` и `id` нужно объявить глобально для передачи во все обработчики.